# S&P500 stock data using YahooSeries returns stock name at the heading. How to make it into a column in R using data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I used yahooSeries and created 500 csv files for stock data for each stock within the S&P 500. Each csv file has 7 columns as below:

```
Date AAPL.Open  AAPL.High   AAPL.Low    AAPL.Close  AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adj.Close  
5/21/15 130.07001   131.63  129.83  131.39  39307500    131.39
5/20/15 130 130.98  129.34  130.06  35965000    130.06
```

The heading includes the stock name, in the above example it is AAPL.For each stock I am interested in the stock name, date and the last 2 columns. I need to construct something like below:

```
Date Ticker Volume Adj.Close
5/21/15 AAPL 39307500   131.39
5/20/15 AAPL 35965000   130.06
```

I have below so far:

```
library(data.table)
files = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
DT = do.call(rbind, lapply(files, fread)
```

How can I restrict columns I want and add the ticker?

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- seq(as.Date('2013-05-22'),as.Date('2015-05-22'),by = 1)
x <- x[!weekdays(x) %in% c('Saturday','Sunday')]
out <- data.table(Date=x)
file.data <- out
setkey(file.data,"Date")
for(i in 1:length(files)){
  file <- fread(files[i],select=c(1,7), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  setnames(file,1,"Date")
  file$Date <- as.Date(file$Date)
  colname <- unlist(strsplit(files[i],"[.]"))[1]
  setnames(file,2,colname)  
  setkey(file,"Date")
  file.data <- file[file.data]
}
```